# Facebook Messenger bot, can't get page_messaging_subscriptions permission and get error

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I developed a dating application bot on Facebook Messenger. In my application, when a match between men and women is established, a notification is sent on messenger by bot. But, when bot sent message, error is happened.
Error message is below.

> “Failed calling Messenger API endpoint messages 400 Bad Request { message: '(#10) This message is sent outside of allowed window. You need page_messaging_subscriptions permission to be able to do it. Learn more about the new policy here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy-overview',”

I applied for page_messaging_subscriptions permission in my application page. However, it was rejected due to being an advertisement purpose. (Actually it is not an advertisement)
Also, I tried other methods. In https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages#messaging_types, If you use messaging tags, it says that 24 + 1 policy can be avoid.
. So, I made message tagged json data. Below

{
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId,
    },
    message: {
    text:”matching text”},
    messaging_type: "MESSAGE_TAG",
    "tag": "PAIRING_UPDATE"
}

I tried it. But same result.
how can I avoid this error?
Is permission mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

If you send a message with TAG, you should not receive this error. `PAIRING_UPDATE` TAG for your use case is what you should use, the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/message-tags) explicitly mention dating apps.

There are tons of ongoing changes from Facebook side so this is probably a bug. You can report it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/support).

It might be, however, expected behaviour. Right now, you can only send text messages and generic templates with TAG. See [this issue](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1984063341668513/?disable_redirect=0) for more details.